# Select where cumulative sum is less than a number (in order of priority)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, cumulative-sum

I have a table with `id`, `cost`, and `priority` columns:

```
create table a_test_table (id number(4,0), cost number(15,2), priority number(4,0));

insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (1, 1000000, 10);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (2, 10000000, 9);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (3, 5000000, 8);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (4, 19000000, 7);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (5, 20000000, 6);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (6, 15000000, 5);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (7, 2000000, 4);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (8, 3000000, 3);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (9, 3000000, 2);
insert into a_test_table (id, cost, priority) values (10, 8000000, 1);
commit;

select 
    id,
    to_char(cost, '$999,999,999') as cost,
    priority
from 
    a_test_table;
```

> ```
>         ID COST            PRIORITY
> ---------- ------------- ----------
>          1    $1,000,000         10
>          2   $10,000,000          9
>          3    $5,000,000          8
>          4   $19,000,000          7
>          5   $20,000,000          6
>          6   $15,000,000          5
>          7    $2,000,000          4
>          8    $3,000,000          3
>          9    $3,000,000          2
>         10    $8,000,000          1
> ```

Starting with the highest priority (descending), I want to select the rows where the `cost` adds up to less than (or equal to) $20,000,000.

The result would look like this:

```
       ID COST            PRIORITY
---------- ------------- ----------
         1    $1,000,000         10
         2   $10,000,000          9
         3    $5,000,000          8
         7    $2,000,000          4

      Total: $18,000,000
```

**How can I do this with Oracle SQL?**

Comment: Why isn't it 16,000,000 (10+9+8+7 exceeds 20,000,000)

Comment: Can you use PL/SQL or does it have to be a SQL query? And if it does have to be SQL then why?

Comment: @SalmanA : Good question. The values in the `priority` column represent a **benefit**. The benefit/priority is more important than squeezing every last dollar out of the budget. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in pure SQL.  I won't swear there isn't a better way.

Basically, it uses a recursive common table expression (i.e., `WITH costed...`) to 
compute every possible combination of elements totaling less than 20,000,000.

Then it gets the first full path from that result.

Then, it gets all the rows in that path.

NOTE: the logic assumes that no `id` is longer than 5 digits.  That's the `LPAD(id,5,'0')` stuff.

```
WITH costed (id, cost, priority, running_cost, path) as 
( SELECT id, cost, priority, cost running_cost, lpad(id,5,'0') path
  FROM   a_test_table
  WHERE  cost <= 20000000
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a.id, a.cost, a.priority, a.cost + costed.running_Cost, costed.path || '|' || lpad(a.id,5,'0')
  FROM   costed, a_test_table a 
  WHERE  a.priority < costed.priority
  AND    a.cost + costed.running_cost <= 20000000),
best_path as (  
SELECT *
FROM   costed c 
where not exists ( SELECT 'longer path' FROM costed c2 WHERE c2.path like c.path || '|%' )
order by path
fetch first 1 row only )
SELECT att.* 
FROM best_path cross join a_test_table att
WHERE best_path.path like '%' || lpad(att.id,5,'0') || '%'
order by att.priority desc;
```

> ```
> +----+----------+----------+
> | ID |   COST   | PRIORITY |
> +----+----------+----------+
> |  1 |  1000000 |       10 |
> |  2 | 10000000 |        9 |
> |  3 |  5000000 |        8 |
> |  7 |  2000000 |        4 |
> +----+----------+----------+
> ```

#### UPDATE - Shorter version

This version uses `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find all the rows in the best group following the recursive CTE:

```
WITH costed (id, cost, priority, running_cost, path) as 
( SELECT id, cost, priority, cost running_cost, lpad(id,5,'0') path
  FROM   a_test_table
  WHERE  cost <= 20000000
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a.id, a.cost, a.priority, a.cost + costed.running_Cost, costed.path || '|' || lpad(a.id,5,'0')
  FROM   costed, a_test_table a 
  WHERE  a.priority < costed.priority
  AND    a.cost + costed.running_cost <= 20000000)
  search depth first by priority desc set ord
SELECT id, cost, priority
FROM   costed c 
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY path
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (STRT ADDON*)
  DEFINE
    ADDON AS ADDON.PATH = PREV(ADDON.PATH) || '|' || LPAD(ADDON.ID,5,'0')
    )
WHERE mno = 1
ORDER BY priority DESC;
```

#### UPDATE -- Even shorter version, using clever idea from the SQL*Server link the OP posted

***Edit: removed use of `ROWNUM=1` in anchor part of recursive CTE, since it depended on the arbitrary order in which rows would be returned.  I'm surprised no one dinged me on that. ***

```
WITH costed (id, cost, priority, running_cost) as 
( SELECT id, cost, priority, cost running_cost
  FROM   ( SELECT * FROM a_test_table
           WHERE  cost <= 20000000
           ORDER BY priority desc
           FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY )
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a.id, a.cost, a.priority, a.cost + costed.running_Cost
  FROM   costed CROSS APPLY ( SELECT b.*
                              FROM   a_test_table b 
                              WHERE  b.priority < costed.priority
                              AND    b.cost + costed.running_cost <= 20000000
                              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                              ) a
)
CYCLE id SET is_cycle TO 'Y' DEFAULT 'N'
select id, cost, priority from costed
order by priority desc
```

Comment: Thanks! You might be interested in @ypercube's latest answer. Cheers.

Comment: Nice! I tried several things to get a single row in the recursive part, I guess I missed some detail when I used CROSS APPLY.

Comment: How does the `CYCLE id SET ...` work in this query and why is it needed?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The `CYCLE id SET...` tells Oracle to stop when it detects a cycle rather than throwing an error.

Comment: Thnx, I didn't know that it could be used in a CTE (without CONNECT BY). That's probably why I was getting errors using CROSS APPLY.

Comment: **Very** nice, guys!

Comment: "The CYCLE id SET... tells Oracle to stop when it detects a cycle rather than throwing an error" — but `is_cycle` is always `N`, so it looks like setting it just works around some subtle implementation bug, is that right?

Comment: Yes, @JackDouglas.  I believe it to be an Oracle bug that the `CYCLE` clause is necessary, but I have no supporting documentation.

Comment: Nice catch regarding `ROWNUM=1`. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

I'm too stupid to do it in plain SQL, so I tried PL/SQL - a function that return s a *table*. Here's how: looping through all rows in a table, I'm calculating the sum; if it is lower than a limit, fine - add row's ID into an array and go on.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_pri (par_limit in number)
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4    l_sum   number := 0;
  5    l_arr   sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select id, cost, priority
  8                  from a_test_table
  9                  order by priority desc
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      l_sum := l_sum + cur_r.cost;
 13      if l_sum <= par_limit then
 14         l_arr.extend;
 15         l_arr(l_arr.last) := cur_r.id;
 16      else
 17         l_sum := l_sum - cur_r.cost;
 18      end if;
 19    end loop;
 20    return (l_arr);
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.
```

Preparing SQL*Plus environment so that the output looks prettier:

```
SQL> break on report
SQL> compute sum of cost on report
SQL> set ver off
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select t.id, t.cost, t.priority
  2  from table(f_pri(&par_limit)) x join a_test_table t on t.id = x.column_value
  3  order by t.priority desc;
Enter value for par_limit: 20000000

        ID       COST   PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1    1000000         10
         2   10000000          9
         3    5000000          8
         7    2000000          4
           ----------
sum          18000000

SQL> /
Enter value for par_limit: 30000000

        ID       COST   PRIORITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1    1000000         10
         2   10000000          9
         3    5000000          8
         7    2000000          4
         8    3000000          3
         9    3000000          2
           ----------
sum          24000000

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

@ypercubeᵀᴹ on the DBA-SE chat posted [this solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f1ebb57bd3516faf0e12eae9c041995). It's pretty consise.

```
with  rt (id, cost, running_total, priority) as
(
    (
    select 
        id,
        cost,
        cost as running_total,
        priority
    from 
        a_test_table
    where cost <= 20000000 
    order by priority desc
    fetch first 1 rows only
    )

    union all

        select 
            t.id,
            t.cost,
            t.cost + rt.running_total,
            t.priority
        from a_test_table  t
             join rt 
             on t.priority < rt.priority      -- redundant but throws
                                              -- "cycle detected error" if omitted

             and t.priority =                             -- needed 
                 ( select max(tm.priority) from a_test_table tm
                   where tm.priority < rt.priority
                     and tm.cost + rt.running_total <= 20000000 )
    )
    select *
    from rt ;
```

*(@ypercubeᵀᴹ is not interested in posting it himself.)*